# Deploying a golang app on heroku, could not import dependency

Tags: heroku

Here is my workspace
**$GOPATH/src/gobot**
When I deploy app without any dependency it works fine, but when I use package it not allow me to deploy. I am using mod.go for dependency under $GOPATH/src/gobot.
This is my code :

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "os"
    tb "gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2"
)

func main() {
     var (
            port      = os.Getenv("PORT")
            publicURL = os.Getenv("PUBLIC_URL")
            token     = os.Getenv("TOKEN")     
        )
        webhook := &tb.Webhook{
            Listen:   ":" + port,
            Endpoint: &tb.WebhookEndpoint{PublicURL: publicURL},
        }
        pref := tb.Settings{
            Token:  token,
            Poller: webhook,
        }
        b, err := tb.NewBot(pref)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        b.Handle("/hello", func(m *tb.Message) {
              b.Send(m.Sender, "You entered "+m.Text)
        })
}
```

When deploy to heroku I got following log

```
remote: -----> Using go1.12.14
remote: -----> Using GB 0.4.4
remote: -----> Running: gb build -tags heroku
remote: FATAL: command "build" failed: failed to resolve import path "gobot": import "gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2": not found: stat /tmp/build_59e73eaedb09a183c064847e8b9ec2ce/src/gopkg.in/tucnak/telebot.v2: no such file or directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Go app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```